# Followed the instructions to enable htaccess on ubuntu 11 to no avail

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, .htaccess, ubuntu-11.04

So I've followed these instructions to setup htaccess on my ubuntu 11

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles

and yet I'm not able to get a directory with an .htaccess file containing the text "Options +Indexes" to list directories when viewed in the browser.

So what gives?

Or perhaps there a more recommended way to enable per-directory listing of the content?

There is nothing in the logs to hint about the problem, only warning about mod_rewrite trying to start 3 times, so perhaps there's yet another config that overrides the /sties_enabled/default one?

Comment: AllowOverride in .conf file changed? To ...?

Comment: AllowOverride changed to All

Comment: Everywhere? `grep -i AllowOverride httpd.conf`, please

Comment: the change was made to /etc/apache2/sites-available/default and that in ubuntu 11 the httpd.conf is rather apache2.conf and that it doesn't have an AllowOverride setting in it.

Comment: Add explicitly to main server config AllowOverride All

Answer (score 0):

Extraction from functional conf

```
DocumentRoot "..."

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Never, ever, EVER set AllowOverride All **OR** Allow from All on ***the OS root directory***!

Comment: For server root, I must note... AllowOverride **All** isn't perfect for production, but usable for troubleshooting stage. Allow from All works nice, my paranoia agree with me

Comment: Seriously? Remind me to avoid you in any professional capacity, then.

Comment: adaptr: I want to get working first, then maybe secure it, besides, there is no one else using that server.That's how it is already - no warnings about parsing the conf files when restarting apache, so no typos, I think